Solving Leetcode's "1813. Sentence Similarity III" using regexes
I'm trying to solve this problem from Leetcode using regexes (just for fun):

You are given two strings sentence1 and sentence2, each
representing a sentence composed of words. A sentence is a list of
words that are separated by a single space with no leading or trailing
spaces. Each word consists of only uppercase and lowercase English
characters.
Two sentences s1 and s2 are considered similar if it is possible
to insert an arbitrary sentence (possibly empty) inside one of these
sentences such that the two sentences become equal. Note that the
inserted sentence must be separated from existing words by spaces.
For example,

s1 = "Hello Jane" and s2 = "Hello my name is Jane" can be made equal by inserting "my name is" between "Hello" and "Jane" in s1.
s1 = "Frog cool" and s2 = "Frogs are cool" are not similar, since    although there is a sentence "s are" inserted into s1, it
is not    separated from "Frog" by a space.

Given two sentences sentence1 and sentence2, return true if
sentence1 and sentence2 are similar. Otherwise, return false.

Assuming small and big are the smaller and bigger sentences respectively, it's easy to check whether small is a prefix/suffix of big:
if re.match(f'^{small} .*$', big) or re.match(f'^.* {small}$', big):
    print('similar')

How to best check if the sentences can be made equal by inserting a new sentence in the middle of small using a regex?

Aside: There's no need to anchor with ^ when you use re.match(). It only matches at the beginning. And if the regexp begins with .*, the anchor has no effect.

I don't think you can do this easily with a regexp. The regexp would have to be all the splits of s1 into words. If s1 is a b c d e you need ^(a {s2} b c d e|a b {s2} c d e|a b c {s2} d e|a b c d {s2} e)$

you could concatinate the two sentenses with " found " and then use a regex like \G(?:(?P<sentense1>\b\w+\b)(?=.*(?P=sentense1)) |(?P<found>found))) and check if group found was matched. Don't know if this suits your needs though

How about this Python demo? Strings need to be sorted by length, also see the regex101 demo. I'm sure this can be done better.

@bobblebubble If you have a solution, post it as an answer below, not as a link in a comment.

@Barmar Of course, not sure if I understsood the question right. I'm curious if my idea works as supposed to and even more of other ideas that are more efficent.

@bobblebubble Shouldn't A lot of words be similar to of because of is in the middle of A lot of words?

@Barmar I guess not, it's Example 2 from OP's provided link (also confused me).

Oh, I got confused about how similarity works. It's not inserting one into the other, it's inserting a third string into the short one to make it equal the long one. A one-word sentence can never be similar to anything because there's no place to insert in the middle. @bobblebubble

I sticked to examples of OP and the provided resource e.g. sentence1 = "Eating right now", sentence2 = "Eating" -> Output: true

My idea needs the strings to be sorted descending by length before using regex. Then concatenate s1 and s2 by newline and check what single part of s1 could be omitted to match s2 (in next line).
import re

def isSimilar(s1, s2):
  
  regex = r'(?is)\A(?!.*  )(\b[a-z ]*)(\b[a-z ]*)(\b[a-z ]*)\n\1\b\3\Z'
  
  # sort strings by length desc
  s = sorted([s1,s2], key=len, reverse=True)
  
  # concat by newline and match pattern
  m = re.match(regex, s[0]+'\n'+s[1])
  
  if(m):
    return 'similar -> ' + m.group(2).strip()
  else:
    return 'not similar!'

See this Python demo at tio.run or a regex demo at regex101 (differs a bit for showcase)
s1 = "Hello Jane"
s2 = "Hello my name is Jane"
print(isSimilar(s1, s2))

will output:
similar -> my name is

Note that this was just playing around, the regex pattern is not efficient. It uses three capture groups and checks if the line after the newline can be completed by the captures of the first and third group (omitting second group). The allowed character-set inside each capture group is set to [a-z ] starting with a word boundary. The lookahead at start checks for not more than one space.

Awesome, this passes 136/138 testcases (after I make the regex case-sensitive). It fails on sentence1 = "A a a"; sentence2 = "Aa a".

@planetp Sounds good! I moved the word boundary at \n to the right of \1 to fix that. Further thinking of equal strings, for now such are considered similar.

This pattern could possibly work:
re.match(r"^(\S+)(?:\s+\S+)*\s+(\S+)\n\1(?:\s+\S+)*\2?$", f"{s1}\n{s2}", re.I)

Testing
import re
    
def sim3(s1: str, s2: str) -> bool:
        return bool(re.match(r"^(\S+)(?:\s+\S+)*\s+(\S+)\n\1(?:\s+\S+)*\2?$", f"{s1}\n{s2}", re.I))

examples = [
        ("My name is Haley", "My Haley", True),
        ("of", "A lot of words", False),
        ("Eating right now", "Eating", True),
        ("Luky", "Lucccky", False)
]

for s1, s2, expected in examples:
    result = sim3(s1, s2)
    print(f"'{s1}' and '{s2}': {result}")
    print(f"Result --> {expected}\n")


119/138 testcases passed (after removing re.I). Failing test case: sentence1 = "eTUny i b R UFKQJ EZx JBJ Q xXz" sentence2 = "eTUny i R EZx JBJ xXz"
